# Terraform destroy resource after imported

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cloud

I've imported **aws_network_interface** in my state on terraform cloud.

I've used my cli with terraform remote backend.

```
terraform import aws_network_interface.default eni-ID
```

The state was updated and the resource imported.
But when I run *terraform plan*, that resource is destroyed **and not recreated**.

Why? What am I wrong?

My imported resource:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "default" {
  subnet_id = "subnet-ID"
}
```

This is terraform plan of network_interface. All destroyed

```
arn : "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:XXX:network-interface/eni-XXX"
description :""
id : "eni-XXX"
interface_type : "interface"
ipv4_prefix_count : 0
ipv4_prefixes :[ ]
ipv6_address_count :0
ipv6_addresses :[ ]
ipv6_prefix_count :0
ipv6_prefixes :[ ]
mac_address :"XXXX"
outpost_arn :""
owner_id : "XXX"
private_dns_name : "ip-XXXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal"
private_ip : "XXX"
private_ips : [
    "XXX"
] -> null
private_ips_count : 0
security_groups :[
    "sg-12345"
    "sg-5678"
] -> null
source_dest_check :true
subnet_id : "subnet-XXX"
tags :{ }
tags_all :{ }
attachment {
    attachment_id : "eni-attach-XXX"
    device_index :    0
    instance : "i-XXX"
}
```

Comment: Is your ENI attached to a different subnet in AWS compared to what you have in Terraform code?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi no, same subnet. I've checked tf state and every thing is the same on AWS

Comment: The Terraform plan should display what is changing in the resource and what is causing the replacement. Is it possible to share the plan for the ENI only (not the whole plan) ?

Comment: Added on main  post. Every thins is destroyed (if applied)

Comment: I would try adding the `private_ips = ["XXX"]` and the `security_groups = ["sg-12345", "sg-5678"]` attributes to `aws_network_interface` and see if Terraform is still trying to destroy it. Unfortunately the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_interface) only specify `interface_type` as triggering a recreation, but it seems the docs are incomplete.

Comment: Added private ip and security groups but it is destroyed again :-/

Comment: The values of the imported interface have to be the same as the values specified in the terraform code. since you are providing only the subnet, the other values are null and don't much the existing ENI. Like Ervin is saying, add values to the code till the interface plan no longer destroys the ENI.

Comment: I added all parameters with the values like as in console, but the resource is still destroyed